# Surface integral and what it computes

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Can anyone tell me what the surface integral of $f(x,y,z)$ actually calculates in  a physical sense in three dimensions?

I know that the surface integral computes the surface area of some given surface:

$$\iint_D ||r_u\times r_v||dA$$

However what does the surface integral below calculate ($f(x,y,z)$ is a continuous function defined on the surface $S$):
$$\iint_S f(x,y,z)dS=\iint_D f(r(u,v))||r_u\times r_v||dA$$

Does it calculate volume? Can anyone explain to me what it computes?

**Edit:** If a smooth parametric surface is given by the parametrization: $$r(u, v) = <x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v)>, (u,v)\in D$$
and $r$ is possibly injective on $D$ except possibly on the boundary of $D$, then the surface area of $S$ over $D$ is given by:

$$\iint_D ||r_u\times r_v||dA$$

Comment: Can you be more talkative about the notations used here ?

Comment: I have tried to edit it to be more specific if it helps thanks.

Comment: When you have a smooth surface, you can parameterize it. What the surface integral does, is it gives you the double integral over the two variables/parameters, which, in turn, gives you the surface area of the parameterized surface.

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx      Here you go, this is a nive website to learn more and do some problems.

Comment: I know which one gives the surface area which is $$\iint_D ||r_u\times r_v||dA$$, but that is not what I am asking, I am asking what $$\iint_D f(r(u,v))||r_u\times r_v||dA$$ represents. I know how to compute these as well, but I want to know what it represents in the physical world what $\iint_D f(r(u,v))||r_u\times r_v||dA$ represents.

Comment: I believe something is mixed up a little bit in the notation. The second expression in your comment *is* the surface integral. $\iint\limits_{S}{{f\left( {x,y,z} \right)\,dS}} = \iint\limits_{D}{{f\left( {\vec r\left( {u,v} \right)} \right)\left\| {{{\vec r}_u} \times {{\vec r}_v}} \right\|\,dA}}$ If not, I am sorry for not understanding the question completely.

Comment: Notice the change in $S$ to $D$ and $dS$ to $dA$ with the parameterization.

Comment: I do not think the notation is wrong because it is a notation I copied out from my textbook. And yes I notice the changes, because $u,v$ is defined on $D$ and its the area element summed over $S$ on the region $D$ hence $dA,$ but at this point it seems like the question what the integral $\iint_D f(r(u,v))||r_u\times r_v||dA$ represents still has not been answered. Like for instance in Layman terms:

$$\iint_D ||r_u\times r_v||dA =\text{surface area of S}$$ 
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx =\text{area under curve f(x)}$$ 
$$\iint_S f(x,y,z)dS=\iint_D f(r(u,v))||r_u\times r_v||dA=\text{???}$$

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now; take a look at this link. http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/surfint/surfint.html    If for example $f$ is a function of density in 3D, you can find the mass by multiplying the value of the function of density with the corresponding area and taking the integral over the whole surface. So you would eventually find the mass of the whole surface. This is an example of course. I hope this was more helpful.

Comment: Yes this was more helpful, thank you for your effort to help me!

Answer (score 4):

Let the domains of integration $B,S,L,C$ and $SW$ be a body, surface, lamina, curve, and a straight wire, respectively, and $x,y,z$ be Cartesian variables.

- The following integrals give **the integration domain's
  length/area/volume**: \begin{align}\int_{SW} &\:\mathrm dx \\\int_C
  &\:\mathrm ds \\\iint_L &\:\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy \\\int_S
  &\:\mathrm dS \\\iiint_B &\:\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm
  dz\end{align}
- If **the integration domain's** (mass) density function is $f,$ then
  the following integrals give its **mass**: \begin{align}\int_{SW} f(x)
  &\:\mathrm dx \\\int_C f(x,y,z) &\:\mathrm ds \\\iint_L
  f(x,y) &\:\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy \\\int_S f(x,y,z)
  &\:\mathrm dS \\\iiint_B f(x,y,z) &\:\mathrm dx\,\mathrm
  dy\,\mathrm dz\end{align}
- The following integrals give **the signed area/volume between the integration domain and the curve $y=f(x)$ or surface $z=f(x,y)$**:
  \begin{align}\int_{SW} f(x) &\:\mathrm dx  \\\int_C f(x,y)
  &\:\mathrm ds \\\iint_L f(x,y) &\:\mathrm dx\,\mathrm
  dy\end{align}